# Architecture for multi-page angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

We have to design a angular multi-page application. And the pages look something like this:

[image]
[image]

I planned to design the page in such a way that each section of the page will have a particular angular controller associated to it and a template will be defined which will be added via the ng-include directive. So basically the page 1 (route ==> '/') will have a 4 different sections which will have 4 different controllers.

Now ofcourse this works fine on a single page, but I am unsure how to define the routes here.

1) Should I have nested controllers, so for page 1 we have a page1Controller and all the other controllers will be under this. Will this be a good design?

or

2) Should I have one controller per page which will make the routing easy and have directives defined for each sections of the page?

Comment: I would use 2 states (for the two pages), with different views (for sections), each view will be a directive.

Comment: Although is not usually recommended, you can use the ngController directive instead of defining the page controller on Routing. I would go that way.

Comment: @MayK : Thanks, By 2 states you mean, both the pages will have just one controller each, right?

Comment: @ItaloAyres: Can you please provide some more details on your approach

Comment: @Mugambo just something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qoa5xs4s/)

Answer (score 2):

I think I would recommend just using multiple named views. Each named view can have its own controller:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/app.tpl.html',
      },
      'section1': {
        controller: 'Section1Controller as vm',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1.tpl.html'
      },
      'section2': {
        controller: 'Section2Controller as vm',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section2.tpl.html'
      },
      'section3': {
        controller: 'Section3Controller as vm',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section3.tpl.html'
      },
      'section4': {
        controller: 'Section4Controller as vm',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section4.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/page2.tpl.html',
      },
      'section1': {
        controller: 'Section1Controller as vm',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1.tpl.html'
      },
      'section2': {
        controller: 'Section2Controller as vm',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section2.tpl.html'
      },
      'section3': {
        controller: 'Section3Controller as vm',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section3.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

Then, when you lay out the views, they look something like this:

```
<div ui-view="section1"></div>
<div ui-view="section2"></div>
<div ui-view="section3"></div>
<div ui-view="section4"></div>
```

Comment: But for this I would have to use the `angular-ui` library. Any chance this can be done natively?

Comment: Worth mentioning this uses UI-Router instead of angular-route

Comment: @Mugambo I find it using angular-ui a better option than default lib. If you are willing to change it.

Comment: @ItaloAyres: Thanks. This seems to be much better options. I will give it a try. Thanks Mike

Comment: @Mugambo, specifically it uses the UI Router. I am unsure how this would be done with `ngRoute`, but I would never recommend using `ngRoute`.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud: I just modified the exiting plunkr but I am not able to get it working with the templateUrl in the state (http://plnkr.co/edit/hE6prAL45AhgV6TQ1RHD?p=preview . ). Request your help on this

Comment: Used the absolute naming convention which solved the issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/BZfQU5SaXCnH3skCXfUj?p=preview

Comment: @Anamadeya, great job because that's actually the changes I was just making!

Answer (score 2):

I would use directives to allow multiple controllers, to re-use code between page1 and page 2, and to prepare for the migration to Angular 2.

Your page would look like:

```
<section1></section1>
<section2></section2>
<section3></section3>
<section4></section4>
```

And you will have to write a directive per section:

```
module.directive('section1', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
    },
    controller: function() { },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: `
      <div>This is section1
      </div>
    `
  }
});
```

Here is an article to [approximate module in Angular 1.x](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/10/18/refactoring-angular-apps-to-components.html#approximating-components-in-angular-1-x)

If you are interested in using TypeScript, here is an [tutorial that includes two pages with 2 shared sections using directives](http://www.digistarters.com/2016/04/20/angular-typescript-gulp-project/) as explained above. Look at the section close to the end called 'Sample pages with shared directives.' The tutorial includes a [github repository](https://github.com/gregorifaroux/digiangularjs).
In that tutorial, page1 looks like

```
h1 page1
page1-section1
page1-section2
```

And, the second page shared the same sections:

```
h1 page2
page2-section2
page2-section1
```

The controllers between page1 and page2 are very similar and creates the section tags using the same/shared directives (DigiSection1.Section1Directive):

```
angular
.module('digiangularjs.page1', [])
.controller('agendaController', Page1Controller)
.directive("page1Section1", [() => new DigiSection1.Section1Directive()])
.directive("page1Section2", [() => new DigiSection2.Section2Directive()])
;
```

And for the second page, we use the same directives, but

```
angular
.module('digiangularjs.page2', [])
.controller('page2Controller', Page2Controller)
.directive("page2Section1", [() => new DigiSection1.Section1Directive()])
.directive("page2Section2", [() => new DigiSection2.Section2Directive()])
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off Mike's answer I would define your route-level templates as single components that are high level layout containers.

```
.state('page1', {
  url: '/page1',
  template: '<page1></page1>'
})
.state('page2', {
  url: '/page2',
  template: '<page2></page2> 
});
```

Then in your `<page>` components (which just dictate layout of nested directives/components) you could do:

```
.component('page1', {
  template: [
    '<section1></section1>',
    '<section2></section2>',
    '<section3></section3>'
  ].join('')
});
```

Also I realize you wrote "multi page applicaton" which would suggest you don't plan on using a router at all. If that is the case your backend will have to take care of the dynamic layout generation, which is a totally different question.